# Database Connection Error in classic Asp

Tags: asp-classic

Following error occur in my Classic ASP website:

```
Database Results Error

The database connection named 'Database1' is undefined.

This problem can occur if:

* the connection has been removed from the web

* the file 'global.asa' is missing or contains errors

* the root folder does not have Scripting permissions enabled

* the web is not marked as an Application Root
```

The `global.asa` file is also been on the server. I don't know where is the problem could you please help??

Basically I am a php developer and doing some asp work for now.

This website is in folder not on the root, like www.example.com/v2. So is this causing the problem?

Here is my global.asa code:

```vbs
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=VBScript RUNAT=Server>
Sub Application_OnStart
    '==FrontPage Generated - startspan==
    Dim FrontPage_UrlVars(1)
    '--Project Data Connection
    Application("Database1_ConnectionString") = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=*******;DATABASE=********;UID=****;PWD=********"
    Application("Database1_ConnectionTimeout") = 60
    Application("Database1_CommandTimeout") = 30
    Application("Database1_CursorLocation") = 3
    Application("Database1_RuntimeUserName") = "*****"
    Application("Database1_RuntimePassword") = "*******"
    '--
    Application("FrontPage_UrlVars") = FrontPage_UrlVars
    '==FrontPage Generated - endspan==
End Sub
Sub Session_OnStart
    FrontPage_StartSession '==FrontPage Generated==
End Sub
Sub FrontPage_StartSession
    On Error Resume Next
    if Len(Application("FrontPage_VRoot")) > 0 then Exit Sub
    ' discover the VRoot for the current page;
    ' walk back up VPath until we find global.asa
    Vroot = Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")
    strG1 = "global.asa"
    strG2 = "Global.asa"
    iCount = 0
     do while Len(Vroot) > 1
        idx = InStrRev(Vroot, "/")
        if idx > 0 then
            Vroot = Left(Vroot,idx)
        else
            ' error; assume root web
            Vroot = "/"
        end if
        if FrontPage_FileExists(Server.MapPath(Vroot & strG1)) then exit do
        if FrontPage_FileExists(Server.MapPath(Vroot & strG2)) then exit do
        if Right(Vroot,1) = "/" then Vroot = Left(Vroot,Len(Vroot)-1)
        iCount = iCount + 1
        if iCount > 100 then
            ' error; assume root web
            Vroot = "/"
            exit do
        end if
    loop
    ' map all URL= attributes in _ConnectionString variables
    Application.Lock
    if Len(Application("FrontPage_VRoot")) = 0 then
        Application("FrontPage_VRoot") = Vroot
        UrlVarArray = Application("FrontPage_UrlVars")
        for i = 0 to UBound(UrlVarArray)
            if Len(UrlVarArray(i)) > 0 then FrontPage_MapUrl(UrlVarArray(i))
        next
    end if
    Application.Unlock
End Sub
Sub FrontPage_MapUrl(AppVarName)
    ' convert URL attribute in conn string to absolute file location
    strVal = Application(AppVarName)
    strKey = "URL="
    idxStart = InStr(strVal, strKey)
    If idxStart = 0 Then Exit Sub
    strBefore = Left(strVal, idxStart - 1)
    idxStart = idxStart + Len(strKey)
    idxEnd = InStr(idxStart, strVal, ";")
    If idxEnd = 0 Then
        strAfter = ""
        strURL = Mid(strVal, idxStart)
    Else
        strAfter = ";" & Mid(strVal, idxEnd + 1)
        strURL = Mid(strVal, idxStart, idxEnd - idxStart)
    End If
    strOut = strBefore & Server.MapPath(Application("FrontPage_VRoot") & strURL) & strAfter
    Application(AppVarName) = strOut
End Sub
Function FrontPage_FileExists(fspath)
    On Error Resume Next
    FrontPage_FileExists = False
    set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Err.Clear
    set istream = fs.OpenTextFile(fspath)
    if Err.Number = 0 then
        FrontPage_FileExists = True
        istream.Close
    end if
    set istream = Nothing
    set fs = Nothing
End Function
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Comment: Please don't put your actual server details in your posts, especially passwords...

Comment: post the code where the error occurs

Comment: every asp file where m using database connection to get result this error occurs could you please tell me some reasons why this is happening?? actually i don't know anything about asp

Comment: i just moved the site from root to subfolder and this error occurs

Comment: Do the respective servers mentioned in the different connection strings in the `Application_OnStart` sub actually exist?

Comment: Which page do you get this error on, @user11? Can you post the ASP code from that page, also, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the v2 directory to an application using IIS manager. This should activate the global.asa. However, you might then run into problems regarding the vroot that seems to have a fallback to "/"

Another option would be to create a separate web site using a different host header. In this case the you can map the application directory v2 to the new web and the application could again use the root directory. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GK5GDkaZdLs on how to create a website with a different host header.